# Profiling Haskell code but excluding library profiling information

Tags: haskell, profiling, libraries

As we all know, when profiling Haskell applications, all dependencies have be installed with profiling information. This is fine, but a problem arises with Haskell packages that have `-auto-all` in their `.cabal` files. This means that I will *always* see their profiling information, even when this is irrelevent to me.

Allow me to present an example where this is problematic. I am building a little game engine, and I do a bunch of work before my game loop loading textures and such with `JuicyPixels`. This isn't code that's interesting to profile - I'm interested in profiling the game loop itself. However, because `JuicyPixels` built itself with `-auto-all`, there doesn't seem to be a way to exclude this information from profiling. As a result, I end up with hundreds of profiling lines that are simply noise.

Is it possible to strip out all of `JuicyPixel`s debugging information (or any library, in the general case)?

Comment: I would patch JuicyPixels and complain to the maintainer. Enabling `-auto-all` unconditionally in the cabal file is an irresponsible thing to do.

Comment: From JuicyPixels' cabal file:

`Ghc-options: -O3 -Wall` and `Ghc-prof-options: -rtsopts -Wall -prof -auto-all`

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka - yes, it does feel that way. Should I maybe start a more public conversation that "`ghc-prof-options` on libraries is considered harmful"? :)

Comment: @AlpMestanogullari - I'm aware of that, was that comment for clarification for other readers? It seems like what I want is for `cabal-install` to ignore `ghc-prof-options`.

Comment: @ocharles yes, that would be good. I imagine a lot of people are unaware of this problem. Be sure to mention that unneeded cost centres not only pollute profiles, but also distort them by having non-zero runtime cost.

Comment: @ocharles my comment was meant as a "partial" answer to Roman's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments suggest that this is a problem with the `cabal` file for JuicyPixels (and if this problem continues to happen in other libraries, then it is also their fault). I started a discussion on the Haskell Cafe (http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/ghc-prof-options-and-libraries-on-Hackage-td5756706.html), and will try and follow up on that.